# PHP Error: Undefined property '$title'. intelephense (1014)

Tags: php

I am getting the error "Undefined property '$title'. intelephense (1014)" for the employee class.

```
class User {
    // Properties are attributes that belong to a class
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $password;

    public function __construct($name, $email, $password) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    function set_name($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function get_name() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

// Inheritence
class Employee extends User {
    public function __construct($name, $email, $password, $title)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $email, $password);
        $this->title = $title;
    }
    public function get_title() {
        return $this->title;
    }
}

$employee1 = new Employee('Sara', 'sara@gmail.com', '123', 'manager');
echo $employee1->get_title;
```

I am also getting the same error for '$get_title' when I try to echo on the last line.

I was expecting to see the employee's title: 'manager'.

Comment: The property title is not defined! Also you need to add parentheses to call a method and not a property. `$employee1->get_title();`

Answer (score 1):

It's not :

```php
echo $employee1->get_title;
```

but :

```php
echo $employee1->get_title();
```

Try using an IDE to develop, this will avoid this kind of error thanks to autocompletion. VSCode for example.

Edit: you forgot the declaration of $title in the class Employees

Comment: This is correct, just want to add somehing to avoid confusion by people reading in the future. VSCode is not an IDE, it's a text editor. It does get close to it thanks to the amount of third party extensions available, but there's still a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Go to VS Code Settings (Ctrl + ,) and search for "intelephens.diagnostics.undefined":

Find and uncheck frm User and Workspace: Enables undefined static property diagnostics. It should work now! [image]

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to declare **public $title;** in class User

```
class User {
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $title;
}
```

the error will be gone